# Generate json body using groovy in jmeter having array inside an array

Tags: groovy, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

I'm trying to generate JSON body dynamically using values in csv file. For this i'm making use of JSR223 PreProcessor with groovy script.
I'm expecting the below format to be generate when i run the groovy script

```
    {
    "transactionId": "100",
    "lineItems": [{
            "lineItemNo": "1",
            "cardInfo": {
                "cardNumber": "3456"
            }
        },
        {
            "lineItemNo": "2",
            "cardInfo": {
                "cardNumber": "45698"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but when i execute script i'm getting below format

```
POST data:
{
    "transactionId": "100",
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "lineItemNo": "1",
            "Cardinfo": [
                9255000012794606,
                9255000012794645
            ]
        },
        {
            "lineItemNo": "1",
            "Cardinfo": [
                9255000012794606,
                9255000012794645
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Script to generate json body

```
File csvFile = new File("D:\\Project Related Docs\\Jmeter\\apache-jmeter-5.0\\bin\\Map_Performance\\Map_New_Auto_jmx\\2Cards.csv")
def cards = csvFile.readLines()
List<String> cardnumbmer = new ArrayList<>()
def counter = 1
cards.eachWithIndex{line,idx->cardnumbmer.add(line)}
log.info("size of csv = "+cardnumbmer.size())
log.info("File conents = "+cardnumbmer[0])

//build the json body
def ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(cardnumbmer.toString())
log.info("cardnumbmer to string = "+cardnumbmer.toString())
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

builder([
    transactionId:"100",
    lineItems:ids.collect{[lineItemNo:"1",Cardinfo: ids.collect{carnumber: it}]}
    ])

//sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',builder.toPrettyString(),'')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
```

--CSV FILE have cardnumbers listed in row-wise look like below
9255000012794606
9255000012794645

Request to help me to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: i think you have to provide an example of `csv` file to understand how you want to build the json...

Comment: CSV file contains only cardnumbers in rows  like - 9255000012794606
9255000012794645

Answer (score 1):

`ids.collect{carnumber: it}` is basically `ids`.  Be explicit about returning the map: `ids.collect{ [carnumber: it] }`

Comment: Updated to return map and explicitly and made a little tweak in the builder code and it solved the issue - builder([
 transactionId:"100",
 lineItems:ids.collect{[lineItemNo:"1",Cardinfo: [Cardnumber:it]]} ])    output is as expected

Answer (score 0):

Below code resolved the problem

```
//build the json body
def ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(cardnumbmer.toString())
log.info("cardnumbmer to string = "+cardnumbmer.toString())
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def count = 1

builder([
    transactionId:"100",
    //lineItems:ids.collect{[lineItemNo:"1",Cardinfo: count.collect{[carnumber: it]}]}
    lineItems:ids.collect{[lineItemNo:count++,Cardinfo: [Cardnumber:it]]}
    ])

//sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',builder.toPrettyString(),'')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
```

Comment: We can also make use of this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989897/concatenating-responses-in-jmeter